# jQuery Masonry Grid, Fade In & Slide Animations

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, jquery-masonry

So I am using the masonry grid on my Brother's restaurant website. What I am seeking is for when the page loads, the container smoothly slides down, and then the images fade in one by one.

[You can see it here](http://droddle.com/taconano/)

Here is my current code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function(){

    var $container = $('#photo_collage');

    $('#container_home').slideDown(1000);

    $container.imagesLoaded( function(){
      $container.masonry({
        itemSelector: '.item',
        gutterWidth: 5,
        isAnimated: true
      });
      $container.animate({opacity: 1}, 700)
    });

  });
</script>

    <div id="container_home">

    <div id="photo_collage">

        <div class="item">
            <img src="images/collage/7.jpg" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <img src="images/collage/3.jpg" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <img src="images/hours_board.jpg" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <img src="images/collage/2.jpg" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <img src="images/collage/4.jpg" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <img src="images/collage/5.jpg" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <img src="images/collage/6.jpg" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <img src="images/collage/1.jpg" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <img src="images/collage/8.jpg" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <img src="images/collage/9.jpg" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <img src="images/collage/10.jpg" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <img src="images/collage/11.jpg" alt="" />
        </div>

        <div class="clear"></div>

    </div><!-- END PHOTO COLLAGE -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use jQuery's `.load()`

Something like:

```
$('#photo_collage').load(function() {
  $(this).slideDown('slow', function() {
    $('.item').fadeIn();  
  });;
});
```

Look at the API though, .load() [can be hit and miss](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/).